# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'str'

Tags: python, selenium

I have the locators.py

```
class MainPageLocatars(object):
  # Login function locators
  TEST           = "//*[starts-with(@id,'table_')]/tbody/tr[%s]"
```

I am calling this locator as below:

```
INDEX_MAP = {
    'First': '1',
    'Last': 'last()'
}

# all locaters for this class are defined here only
class ListView(Page):

    def __init__(self, driver, index):

        if index not in INDEX_MAP:
            raise ValueError("Invalid index %s" % index)

        self.driver = driver
        self.row = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(MainPageLocatars.FRAMEONE % (INDEX_MAP[index])
```

This is the right way to do it?

this is the error I am getting:

```
   self.row = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(MainPageLocatars.FRAMEONE % (INDEX_MAP[index]))
   self.row = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(MainPageLocatars.FRAMEONE % (INDEX_MAP[index]))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'str'
```

Comment: Evidently `MainPageLocatars.FRAMEONE` is a tuple. What were you expecting `%` to do to it?

Comment: According to the posted code, `MainPageLocatars` does not even have a `FRAMEONE` attribute...

Comment: Try to add a "comma" in the end of `...MainPageLocatars.FRAMEONE % (INDEX_MAP[index],))`.

Comment: @RafaelAguilar Then he'll probably just get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'tuple'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
MainPageLocatars.FRAMEONE % (INDEX_MAP[index])
```

By:

```
MainPageLocatars.TEST % (INDEX_MAP[index])
```

To do string formatting.

Comment: oh i am not sure why i added frameone. thanks a lot. it works.